# Is there a conjunctive that's roughly equivalent to "in that case" or "if so"?

Tags: grammar, word-requests, adverbs

Say for example I want to say something like

> レストランに行きたいですか？行きたかったら、私は予約をしておきますよ。

It feels cumbersome to me to have to repeat the verb 行くin the second sentence.  Is there a conjunctive that I should use to replace the phrase いきたかったら?  Does 場合は carry a similar connotation?  Or is it just normal in Japanese to just repeat the verb here?

Comment: If you really want to avoid repeating, you can try "もしそうなら" meaning if so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In that case" / "if so":

- **なら** (colloquial)
- **だったら** (colloquial)
- **でしたら** (politely colloquial)
- **であれば** (formal, bookish)

Much like だから or でも which you may know, the conjugated forms of the copula だ can function as independent conjunctions (not conjunctive particles) at the beginning of a sentence, referring to the context before. It may sound surprising, but this is perfectly grammatical. The politeness or other nuances all conform to normal grammar that you need to adjust to.

> レストランに行きたいですか？なら、予約しておきますよ。

Comment: How does ならば fit into the set? I think I've heard it beginning a sentence before

Comment: @Angelos ならば would sound a bit old-fashioned and/or affected in speech today.

Comment: Thanks a million!  I never would have realized the broader pattern going on with using the copula to form conjunctions, but it's super intuitive now that you've pointed it out :)